# error get date time laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Hi** 
i bought a project from someone ,when i run it i have a problem .
the problem is when i try to load match with CURL from this link http://www.planetwin365.com/ControlsSkin/OddsEvent.aspx?ShowLinkFastBet=0&showDate=1&showGQ=1&rnd=049759534356372304&EventID=7944&GroupSep=undefined
to my database i show me this problem 
[image]

this is my code

```
 private function get_date_time($date,$time){
        if(!Auth::user()->hasRole(['correction', 'admin'])){
            return redirect('/');
        }
        //sabato 4 giugno 2016
        $dates = explode(' ',$date);
        $times = str_replace('.',':',$time);
        switch ($dates[2]){
            case 'gennaio':
                $month = 01;
                break;
            case 'febbraio':
                $month = 02;
                break;
            case 'marzo':
                $month = 03;
                break;
            case 'aprile':
                $month = 04;
                break;
            case 'maggio':
                $month = 05;
                break;
            case 'giugno':
                $month = 06;
                break;
            case 'luglio':
                $month = 07;
                break;
            case 'agosto':
                $month = 8;
                break;
            case 'settembre':
                $month = 9;
                break;
            case 'ottobre':
                $month = 10;
                break;
            case 'novembre':
                $month = 11;
                break;
            case 'dicembre':
                $month = 12;
                break;
            default:
                $month = 01;
        }
        //2016-04-24 05:09:03
        return $dates[3].'-'.$month.'-'.$dates[1].' '.$times;
    }
```

please help me

Comment: what does `$date` contain?

Comment: @Kisaragi  // date
                        $date = $table->find('.cqDateTbl')[0];
                        if($date != null){
                            $p_date = $date->text;

Comment: Yeah, but the actual value? It seems you are not getting the expected value here (Y m d).

Comment: Need a sample of the value, not the assignment.

Comment: @Kisaragi sir this is my code complete : https://hastebin.com/qapaqewevo.bash

Comment: @FelippeDuarte this is my code sir : https://hastebin.com/qapaqewevo.bash

Comment: Sir/ma'am: No. That's about 400 lines. Please post a possible value to your `$date` variable.

Comment: We already have your code, we need to know what data you have in your variable. Try `var_dump($date);` and show the output for us. It's probably something like `2017 01 26`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte sir when i search var_dump($date); it's show me not found i upload all the file here hastebin.com/qapaqewevo.bash

Comment: @Kisaragi i upload all the file here https://hastebin.com/qapaqewevo.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `$dates` array has only three elements. Please remember the first index in an array is 0 not 1. I cannot confirm it as this service doesn't work in my country, but the following should do the trick.

```
switch ($dates[1]){

//...

$day = str_replace('.','',$dates[0]);
return $dates[2].'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$times;
```

Comment: it's work but there is a problem in the month i load a matches in february but in the database it's loaded in february

Comment: Not sure I understand. Does it work now? What is the problem with the database?

Comment: the match wil play 
2017-02-16 21:05:00 the problem is it save in the database at 
2017-01-16 21:05:00  sorry for my bad english

Comment: On the error message I see `februar`, but in your code you match `febbraio` as February.  It's not matched therefore it will return default 1 (January). Months in your code seem Italian. Maybe you have to force the API to respond in Italian, or modify your code.